# Matching names in a df column then adding a number to pair them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with two columns. The goal is to read from the `Name` column and add a number to the `Pairing` column, but if there is more than one name of the same, they get the same number. For example:

```
Name    | Pairing  
-----------
Charles |1   
Scott   |2   
Scott   |2   
Anne    |3   
Anne    |3
Anne    |3
Bart    |4
```

I've tried using `str.replace`  but with that I believe I can only use key words. Any tips on how to tackle this is much appreciated. Thank you!

Edit:

So I made some adjustments, now I'm trying to add a 3rd column into the mix:

```
Name    | type  |      Pairing 
---------------------------
Charles |Circle      | 1
Scott   |Square      | 2
Scott   |Triangle    | 3
Anne    |Rectangle   | 4
Anne    |Rectangle   | 4
Anne    |Oval        | 5
Bart    |Octagon     | 6
```

I'm trying to get the results in the `Pairing` column, so as long as what matches in the `Name` & `type` they get the same numerical value.

I've tried this `df['Pairing'] = pd.factorize(df['Name'].str[:6])[0] + pd.factorize(df['type'].str[:6])[0]` which kinda works but it is not giving me accurate results.

Is there also away to start the factorize index at 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `factorize`:

```
df['Pairing'] = pd.factorize(df['Name'])[0]
```

Comment: Thanks you! Can this method work if I want to match the first few characters of the strings in the name column? Say I have ```Scott``` and ```Scott2``` I'd like them to have the same number

Comment: You need to extract that few characters. For example `df['Name'].str[:5]` will give you the first five characters, `df['Name'].str.extract('^([\D]+)[0]')` will extract the first non-digits characters.

Comment: Thanks again, I have a few more things to work out but this is a good starting point!